# How to play a A in octave

Tags: linux, octave, audio

How to play a A (3rd octave) in Octave using playaudio() function? I use Ubuntu Linux. Its frequency it's 440 Hz.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Haven't touched Octave in a while and remember having trouble with sound on OSX (apparently the [audio](http://octave.sourceforge.net/audio/index.html) package works well in linux). The audio package should have a **[sound()](http://octave.sourceforge.net/audio/function/sound.html)** function would make your task easy:

```
%sample rate - 22050
sr = [0:1/22050:1];
% A - 440Hz using sine
a = sin(2*pi*440*sr);
%play
sound(a)
```

Unfortunately playaudio() doesn't work on my machine:

```
octave-3.0.3:15> playaudio(x)
sh: /dev/dsp: Permission denied
```

Still, I've tested sound() and got a tone. 
If you have issues with the sound() function, you can try to use a custom sound() function:

```
function sound(x, fs)
  if(nargin == 1 || isempty(fs))
    fs = 8000;
  endif
  if(rows(x) != length(x))
    x = x'
  endif
  if(playrec('isInitialised'))
    playrec('reset');
  endif

  playrec('init', fs, 3, 1);

  playrec('play', x, 1:size(x,2));
endfunction
```

HTH, as Octave isn't my area of expertise.